# Is it possible to create multiple SSL certificates for providers that send APNs to the same Application?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

I realize there was a question about allowing multiple servers to send Push Notifications to the same application using the same SSL Certificate, but my question is different.

Suppose that the developer of a single iOS application would like to allow multiple providers to send Push Notifications to his application, but wants to control which providers have the authority to send APNs to his App (and to be able to revoke that privilege from any one of them).

If all the providers have the same certificate, in order to block one of them from sending APNs, he has to block them all (by revoking the Push SSL Certificate, and getting a new one). 
Is it possible to get from Apple multiple Push SSL Certificates for the same Application?

That would make it possible to assign a unique certificate for each provider, which would allow to block a single provider without blocking the rest.

On the Apple Provisioning Portal there doesn't seem to be a possibility to create more than one Push SSL Certificate for the same Application and the same environment (Development/Production), but I wanted to be sure whether it can't be done.

Comment: Create an API and have your multiple sources send "notifications"  to your sytem and then you send the actual notification through APN unless you revoked a sources privileges then simply ignore it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since no one answered my question, I'll answer it myself.

The answer to that question used to be no but it seems that Apple made some changes in the provisioning portal (which is now called `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`), and now it's possible to define multiple certificates for the same application and the same environment.

[image]

Comment: so @eran, my app currently is using a notification provider, but I want to move away from it, and start using another one. I could just create an additional certificate and use one during development safely?

Comment: @PatoSalazar I haven't worked on Apple Push Notifications for the past few years, so my knowledge may be outdated, but I suggest you revoke/cancel the existing certificate (the one you shared with that provider), and create a new one.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can create only 2 apple push certificates for one App ID and no more.

Apple developer center does not allow me to create more then two and same experience has my friend.
I don´t see how your task can be solved now. In my opinion Apple does not want to support such products. Maybe you can do more with Enterprise Developer account but I don´t have one. So maybe anyone else can tell us if it allows to create more push certificates for on iOS application.

Comment: In our case, the developer center doesn't let us create more than 2 for an Enterprise Account app, but for an App Store app it's offering us the ability to create another even though we already have 2.