# Development aps cert has been revoked, why it can still push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have two curious question about aps.
1  One app can support two aps server pushing together?   I have a server A which can push normally. But when I begin to use Server B to push, A cannot push.

2 I have revoke all development aps cert, but server B still can push.  Why? How to stop B pushing?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I will recommend you to first go through this tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Hope tis will help

Comment: Sorry, I am not a beginner. I am trying to deal with the problem.

Comment: So you are telling that , when server B start pushing then A can not push , will you explain me why A will still push , do you know public private key combination and all that and who can push ?

Comment: i look up here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875992/single-ssl-certificate-over-multiple-servers-to-send-push-notifications-to-same

Comment: Look there too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365302/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-ssl-certificates-for-providers-that-send-apns/15902579#15902579